# Data change Audit log with ability to revert to old value on review

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am in need of tracking data changes that are made by Junior Analysts in my application. The application is designed to Insert, Update and delete data from sql server. I need the Jr. Analyst to be able to update the database real time, and allow a Senior Analyst to identify the fields the Jr. Analyst has edited, and be able to accept or reject the update as a QC process every so often (weekly).

In the case of Accept, the change log would delete the record of change.
In the case of Reject, the value would roll back to the old value and delete the record of change.

I have two stored procedure's to handle the insert and delete of change records.

My question is what is the best way to track the old value for reverting purpose. Should I:

A. Create a textBox_Enter event and save the original value to string value. If the old value does not equal the new value, insert a record.
B. Is there a built in way to get the old value.
C. A better way that I am not aware of.

Comment: Personally, I would record it at the discrete transaction level (each save operation by the Junior Analyst). Two suggestions 1) don't delete the record of change, just mark it as accepted/rejected/pending and 2) Add to the record of change whenever a record is reverted due to a rejection.

Comment: @AWinkle How would I record the old value though in case I wanted to revert to old value?